# Intel Xdk backend implementation

Tags: apk

I have been studying about Intel XDK about how to program for cross platforms, for now I'm that much clear that we can program the interface using HtML,css and Js but don't know How to implement the backend code!!! (whether using js or php) ?

Answer (score 0):

Intel xdk stops their support, we can only work with the last release.

For the above question, you can add HTML file for the UI design and add its backend file as javascript file and add the javascript file in HTML.